# Is it possible to test for the base of a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, typechecking

Ok, this may sound odd, but I need to test if an `object` passed to me is of type `ModelItem<T>` where I don't care what `T` actually is.  In other words, if it's a `ModelItem<int>`, `ModelItem<string>` or `ModelItem<Foo>`, then I need to return `true`.

Note: If I were the owner of `ModelItem<T>`, I would think to just define an interface of type `IModelItem` and assign it as part of the `ModelItem<T>` definition, but I don't have access to the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's possible:

```
public bool IsIt(object thing)
{
    var type = thing.GetType();
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyThing<>);
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Testing it:

```
IsIt(new MyThing<int>()).Dump();
IsIt(new MyThing<string>()).Dump();
IsIt(new MyThing<Foo>()).Dump();
IsIt(5).Dump();
```

Returns

```
True
True
True
False
```